# Keep getting error runing colima FATA[0001] error starting vm: error at 'starting': exit status 1

Tags: qemu, colima

I downloaded the Colima but I wanted to run it however it keeps showing: `FFATA[0022] error starting vm: error at 'starting': exit status 1` like this so I don't know how to solve the problem. Please help me

- Colima version: `colima version 0.5.5`
- lima version: `limactl version 0.17.2`
- Operating System: `macOS Intel` `Ventura 13.3.1`

```
> Using the existing instance "colima-k8s-amd64"
> "QEMU binary \"/Users/david.coutinho/.colima/_wrapper/4e1b408f843d1c63afbbdcf80c40e4c88d33509f/bin/qemu-system-x86_64\" is not properly signed with the \"com.apple.security.hypervisor\" entitlement" error="failed to run [codesign --verify /Users/david.coutinho/.colima/_wrapper/4e1b408f843d1c63afbbdcf80c40e4c88d33509f/bin/qemu-system-x86_64]: exit status 1 (out=\"/Users/david.coutinho/.colima/_wrapper/4e1b408f843d1c63afbbdcf80c40e4c88d33509f/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: code object is not signed at all\\nIn architecture: x86_64\\n\")"
> You have to sign the QEMU binary with the "com.apple.security.hypervisor" entitlement manually. See https://github.com/lima-vm/lima/issues/1742 .
> exiting, status={Running:false Degraded:false Exiting:true Errors:[] SSHLocalPort:0} (hint: see "/Users/david.coutinho/.lima/colima-k8s-amd64/ha.stderr.log")
FATA[0022] error starting vm: error at 'starting': exit status 1
❯ cat /Users/david.coutinho/.lima/colima-k8s-amd64/ha.stderr.log
{"level":"debug","msg":"Creating iso file /Users/david.coutinho/.lima/colima-k8s-amd64/cidata.iso","time":"2023-09-28T14:50:00+01:00"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"Using /var/folders/3s/y_04zpqd1xs8sh4l39fmnjpm0000gq/T/diskfs_iso2067552449 as workspace","time":"2023-09-28T14:50:00+01:00"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"OpenSSH version 9.0.1 detected","time":"2023-09-28T14:50:00+01:00"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"AES accelerator seems available, prioritizing aes128-gcm@openssh.com and aes256-gcm@openssh.com","time":"2023-09-28T14:50:00+01:00"}
{"level":"fatal","msg":"failed to run [/Users/david.coutinho/.colima/_wrapper/4e1b408f843d1c63afbbdcf80c40e4c88d33509f/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -M none -accel help]: stdout=\"\", stderr=\"dyld[77569]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/capstone/lib/libcapstone.4.dylib\\n  Referenced from: \u003c2081BA1F-138F-3663-95A3-F7848EF7CD0D\u003e /usr/local/Cellar/qemu/8.0.3/bin/qemu-system-x86_64\\n  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/capstone/lib/libcapstone.4.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/capstone/lib/libcapstone.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/capstone/lib/libcapstone.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libcapstone.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcapstone.4.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/usr/local/Cellar/capstone/5.0.1/lib/libcapstone.4.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/Cellar/capstone/5.0.1/lib/libcapstone.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/capstone/5.0.1/lib/libcapstone.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libcapstone.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcapstone.4.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)\\n\"","time":"2023-09-28T14:50:00+01:00"}
```

Comment: **WARNING TO THE READER** - DO NOT BLINDLY COLIMA DELETE AS SUGGESTED IN THE TOP ANSWER - CHECK IF YOU HAVE ANY DATA STORED IN THE CONTAINERS FIRST BECAUSE THEY WILL BE COMPLETELY DELETED. SEE COMMENTS IN THE TOP ANSWER (BECAUSE I DIDNT AND LOST DATA)

a new answer that results in graceful recovery instead of data loss would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I too had a similar issue and was able to fix by,

```
colima delete
colima start
```

Found this solution in Colima's issue section in GitHub - [FATA[0000] error starting vm: error at 'starting': exit status 1](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/issues/502#issuecomment-1411983204)

You can check Colima's issue section for similar issues and associated discussions.

Comment: WARNING: This will also delete your docker images and associated containers.

Comment: BIG BIG WARNING: THIS INCLUDES ALL POSTGRES INSTANCES INSIDE CONTAINERS. I just lost all my data thanks to blindly running colima delete - which got colima working again, but of course i forgot to do any backup of the db first.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with macos ventura, the only solution that fixed it for me was:

```
brew uninstall colima
brew uninstall docker
```

after that i tried to install colima without docker:

```
brew install colima
```

then, as expected, i have colima complaining that there is no docker dependency

So, I install docker:

```
brew install docker
```

And finally, i installed colima:

```
brew install colima
colima start
```

this was the only solution that worked for me.